# Admin grid unwanted columns appears and no record are found

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, uicomponent

I create a custom module. My admin grid is very strange because it shows randoms columns after the columns I define in my ui-component and no records are found but in database there are records (the add functionality works).

So here is a capture :
[image]

So here is my ui component code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- Integration -->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- we define a provider -->
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">review_listing.review_listing_data_source</item>
            <!-- same string as above -->
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">review_listing.review_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <!-- define column type -->
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">review_columns</item>
        <!-- Button to add new item -->
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Review</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item> <!-- magento will translate it by jobs/department/new -->
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <!-- Data source -->
    <dataSource name="review_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">ReviewGridDataProvider</argument> <!-- Data provider class -->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">review_listing_data_source</argument> <!-- provider defined above -->
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">review_id</argument> <!-- Primary key -->
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument> <!-- URL name parameter -->

            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Primary key column name -->
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">review_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- Container Listing Top -->
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <!-- Button to manage views -->
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">review_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <!-- Button to manage columns -->
        <container name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">review_listing.review_listing.review_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
    </container>



    <!-- Columns -->
    <columns name="review_columns">
        <!-- ID Column -->
        <column name="review_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is my di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Create our type ReviewGridDataProvider -->
    <virtualType name="ReviewGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">MyVendor\CustomerReview\Model\Resource\Review\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">ReviewGridFilterPool</argument> <!-- Define new object for filters -->
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- Create our type ReviewGridFilterPool -->
    <virtualType name="ReviewGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <!-- Type for review_listing_data_source -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="review_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\CustomerReview\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Review\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <!-- Simulate our class MyVendor\CustomerReview\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Review\Collection -->
    <virtualType name="MyVendor\CustomerReview\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Review\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">myvendor_review</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">MyVendor\CustomerReview\Model\ResourceModel\Review</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

My Database table is named "myvendor_review" and the PK is review_id

Answer (score 0):

In reality ui-component seems to works like layout. So I create an ui-component for a different review system.

I named it by using the prefix "review" (review_listing_data_source, review_listing, ReviewGridDataProvider...) but in practice, it will get the data of the magento module review ui-component and include them in the ui-component. So I changed every review prefix for "customerreview" and now it works well ;)